# Finding an image within an image

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 images. One image is a large image and the second one is a small one.
The small image has a copy of itself within the large image. I am wanting to find the coordinates of where the second image is located within the large image, a 'find feature' in other words.

e.g, I might have an image with the word "Test" in it. And I want to find the coordinates of the letter 'e'...

Not sure if that makes sense....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to read up on image feature extraction literature. This is a nontrivial task, nothing that we could explain here in a few lines. There are plenty of things to consider e.g. whether it is an exact copy, or just very similar, whether you allow rotation and rescaling or not etc.

Sorry, your question is just way too general to be answered here. So grab a **book** on image similarity search and computer vision, so you can come up with a more precise answer. Thank you.

Comment: "There are plenty of things to consider e.g. whether it is an exact copy, or just very similar, whether you allow rotation and rescaling or not etc." It is an exact copy... same size, same rotation (I am not sure if that makes it easier to answer). I try to find a book

Answer (score 0):

You should look at correlation based method. 
Correlation would be the good keyword to look for given your indications ;)